# Memory management issue while Call Obj-C in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

I'm currently developing a native plugin for a Capcitor app. I have very little experience with native iOS development, Swift and Obj-C.

I use a framework (FunSDK) which is written in C++.
I call this in an Objective-C++ wrapper.
As described here: https://medium.com/@cecilia.humlelu/set-up-c-library-dependencies-in-swift-projects-5dc2ccd2ddaf

The wrapper is then available in Swift via the bridging header.
This works so far, I can call the functions from the framework and they are executed correctly.
However, the functions of the framework are executed asynchronously. When a result is obtained, the “OnFunSDKResult” method is always executed.

During this step I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while debugging. Then I ticked “Zombie objects” under the diagnostics settings. This causes execution to stop with an EXC_BREAKPOINT.

As I understand it, after executing the iniXMSDK method, the FunSDKWrapper class is cleared from memory before executing the "OnFunSDKResult" method?

I have also already integrated a completionHandler, which is only called in the "OnFunSDKResult" method so that data is transferred to the Swift class. However, that doesn't help either.

I have no idea how to proceed.
I hope somebody can help me.

If you need any more information, I would be happy to provide it.

The FunSDKWrapper.mm

```
//
//  FunSDKWrapper.m
//  App
//
//  Created by Sysprobs on 12/8/23.
//

#import "FunSDKWrapper.h"
#import "FunSDK/FunSDK.h"

#import <XMNetInterface/Reachability.h>

@implementation FunSDKWrapper

-(NSString *)iniXMSDK:(int)test completion:(void (^)(int result))completionHandler{
    
    self.initCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
    
    self.msgHandle = FUN_RegWnd((__bridge void *)self);
    
    FUN_Init();
    Fun_LogInit(self.msgHandle, "", 0, "", LOG_UI_MSG);
    FUN_XMCloundPlatformInit("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", 1);
    FUN_InitNetSDK();
    
    FUN_SetFunStrAttr(EFUN_ATTR_SAVE_LOGIN_USER_INFO,SZSTR([self GetDocumentPathWith:@"UserInfo.db"]));
        
    FUN_SetFunStrAttr(EFUN_ATTR_USER_PWD_DB, SZSTR([self GetDocumentPathWith:@"password.txt"]));
    
    FUN_SetFunStrAttr(EFUN_ATTR_UPDATE_FILE_PATH,SZSTR([self GetDocumentPathWith:@""]));
    FUN_SetFunStrAttr(EFUN_ATTR_TEMP_FILES_PATH,SZSTR([self GetDocumentPathWith:@""]));
        
    FUN_SetFunIntAttr(EFUN_ATTR_AUTO_DL_UPGRADE, 0);
    
    FUN_SetFunStrAttr(EFUN_ATTR_CONFIG_PATH,SZSTR([self GetDocumentPathWith:@"APPConfigs"]));
    
    FUN_SetFunIntAttr(EFUN_ATTR_SUP_RPS_VIDEO_DEFAULT, 1);
    
    FUN_SetFunIntAttr(EFUN_ATTR_SET_NET_TYPE, [self getNetworkType]);
    
    FUN_SysInit("arsp.xmeye.net;arsp1.xmeye.net;arsp2.xmeye.net", 15010);
    FUN_InitNetSDK();

    FUN_SysGetDevList(self.msgHandle, SZSTR(@"xxxx") , SZSTR(@"xxxx"),0);
        
    return @"test";
}

- (void)searchLanDevices {
     FUN_DevSearchDevice(self.msgHandle, 4000, 0);
}


// NSDocument/fileName
- (NSString *)GetDocumentPathWith:(NSString *) fileName {
    NSString* path = [self documentsPath];
    if (fileName != nil) {
        path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
        path = [path stringByAppendingString:fileName];
    }
    return path;
}
//NSDocument
- (NSString *)documentsPath {
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [pathArray lastObject];
    return path;
}

-(int)getNetworkType {
    Reachability*reach=[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
    
    //判断当前的网络状态
    switch([reach currentReachabilityStatus]){
            
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
            return 1;
            
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
            return 2;
            
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}


- (void)OnFunSDKResult:(NSNumber *) pParam {
    NSInteger nAddr = [pParam integerValue];
    MsgContent *msg = (MsgContent *)nAddr;
    switch (msg->id) {
        case EMSG_SYS_GET_DEV_INFO_BY_USER:{
            self.initCompletionHandler(1);  
            if (msg->param1 < 0){
                //fehler
                NSLog(@"Fehler beim XMCloud login");
            }else{
                
                char devJson[750*500];
                FUN_GetFunStrAttr(EFUN_ATTR_GET_USER_ACCOUNT_DATA_INFO, devJson, 750*500);
                NSLog(@"Geraeteliste: = %s",devJson);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}


@end
```

The Swift Class

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

/**
 * Please read the Capacitor iOS Plugin Development Guide
 * here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/ios
 */
@objc(xmsdkPlugin)
public class xmsdkPlugin: CAPPlugin {
    private let implementation = xmsdk()

    @objc func echo(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        let value = call.getString("value") ?? ""
        call.resolve([
            "value": implementation.echo(value)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func initXMSDK(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        //let devId = call.getString("devId") ?? ""
        
           
        let wrapper = FunSDKWrapper();
        let resp = wrapper.iniXMSDK(1, completion: {(result) -> Void in
            NSLog("Completion von iniXMSDK")
        });
        
        call.resolve([
            "status": resp
        ])

    }    
    
}
```

Errorlog with EXC_BREAKPOINT:

```
App`invocation function for block in UI_SendMsg(int, XMSG*):
    0x102bed8f4 <+0>:   sub    sp, sp, #0x70
    0x102bed8f8 <+4>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x40]
    0x102bed8fc <+8>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x50]
    0x102bed900 <+12>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x60]
    0x102bed904 <+16>:  add    x29, sp, #0x60
    0x102bed908 <+20>:  mov    x19, x0
    0x102bed90c <+24>:  ldr    x8, [x0, #0x20]
    0x102bed910 <+28>:  ldr    w9, [x8, #0x18]
    0x102bed914 <+32>:  str    w9, [sp, #0x8]
    0x102bed918 <+36>:  ldr    q0, [x8, #0x20]
    0x102bed91c <+40>:  stur   q0, [sp, #0xc]
    0x102bed920 <+44>:  ldr    x9, [x8, #0x38]
    0x102bed924 <+48>:  ldr    x10, [x8, #0x50]
    0x102bed928 <+52>:  stp    x10, x9, [sp, #0x20]
    0x102bed92c <+56>:  ldr    w9, [x8, #0x30]
    0x102bed930 <+60>:  str    w9, [sp, #0x34]
    0x102bed934 <+64>:  str    x8, [sp, #0x38]
    0x102bed938 <+68>:  adrp   x0, 6283
    0x102bed93c <+72>:  add    x0, x0, #0x60             ; g_wndIndexLock
    0x102bed940 <+76>:  bl     0x102bdd34c               ; XBASIC::CLock::Lock at Lock.cpp:58:29
    0x102bed944 <+80>:  adrp   x8, 6283
    0x102bed948 <+84>:  ldr    x10, [x8, #0x38]
    0x102bed94c <+88>:  cbz    x10, 0x102bed98c          ; <+152> at UIInterface.mm:130:24
    0x102bed950 <+92>:  ldr    w9, [x19, #0x28]
    0x102bed954 <+96>:  adrp   x11, 6283
    0x102bed958 <+100>: add    x11, x11, #0x38           ; g_id_wnd + 8
    0x102bed95c <+104>: mov    x8, x11
    0x102bed960 <+108>: ldr    w12, [x10, #0x20]
    0x102bed964 <+112>: cmp    w12, w9
    0x102bed968 <+116>: cset   w12, lt
    0x102bed96c <+120>: csel   x8, x8, x10, lt
    0x102bed970 <+124>: ldr    x10, [x10, w12, uxtw  #3]
    0x102bed974 <+128>: cbnz   x10, 0x102bed960          ; <+108> [inlined] std::__1::less<int>::operator()(int const&, int const&) const at operations.h:487:17
    0x102bed978 <+132>: cmp    x8, x11
    0x102bed97c <+136>: b.eq   0x102bed98c               ; <+152> at UIInterface.mm:130:24
    0x102bed980 <+140>: ldr    w10, [x8, #0x20]
    0x102bed984 <+144>: cmp    w9, w10
    0x102bed988 <+148>: b.ge   0x102bed9dc               ; <+232> at UIInterface.mm:126:21
    0x102bed98c <+152>: adrp   x0, 6283
    0x102bed990 <+156>: add    x0, x0, #0x60             ; g_wndIndexLock
    0x102bed994 <+160>: bl     0x102bdd354               ; XBASIC::CLock::Unlock at Lock.cpp:63:31
    0x102bed998 <+164>: adrp   x0, 4324
    0x102bed99c <+168>: add    x0, x0, #0xb00            ; @"NO MSG Object....."
    0x102bed9a0 <+172>: bl     0x1038af9a0               ; symbol stub for: NSLog
    0x102bed9a4 <+176>: ldr    x0, [x19, #0x20]
    0x102bed9a8 <+180>: ldr    x9, [x0, #0x8]
    0x102bed9ac <+184>: ldaxr  x8, [x9]
    0x102bed9b0 <+188>: sub    x10, x8, #0x1
    0x102bed9b4 <+192>: stlxr  w11, x10, [x9]
    0x102bed9b8 <+196>: cbnz   w11, 0x102bed9ac          ; <+184> [inlined] InterlockedDecrement(long*) at OS.h:120:9
    0x102bed9bc <+200>: sub    w8, w8, #0x1
    0x102bed9c0 <+204>: cmp    w8, #0x0
    0x102bed9c4 <+208>: b.gt   0x102beda24               ; <+304> at UIInterface.mm:143:5
    0x102bed9c8 <+212>: tbnz   w8, #0x1f, 0x102beda18    ; <+292> [inlined] XBASIC::IReferable::Release() at Referable.h:95:17
    0x102bed9cc <+216>: ldr    x8, [x0]
    0x102bed9d0 <+220>: ldr    x8, [x8, #0x8]
    0x102bed9d4 <+224>: blr    x8
    0x102bed9d8 <+228>: b      0x102beda24               ; <+304> at UIInterface.mm:143:5
    0x102bed9dc <+232>: ldp    x20, x21, [x8, #0x28]
    0x102bed9e0 <+236>: adrp   x0, 6283
    0x102bed9e4 <+240>: add    x0, x0, #0x60             ; g_wndIndexLock
    0x102bed9e8 <+244>: bl     0x102bdd354               ; XBASIC::CLock::Unlock at Lock.cpp:63:31
    0x102bed9ec <+248>: cbz    x20, 0x102bed998          ; <+164> at UIInterface.mm:139:13
    0x102bed9f0 <+252>: adrp   x8, 4330
    0x102bed9f4 <+256>: ldr    x0, [x8, #0x5e8]
    0x102bed9f8 <+260>: add    x2, sp, #0x8
    0x102bed9fc <+264>: bl     0x1038b5a00               ; objc_msgSend$numberWithUnsignedInteger:
    0x102beda00 <+268>: mov    x3, x0
    0x102beda04 <+272>: mov    x0, x20
    0x102beda08 <+276>: mov    x2, x21
    0x102beda0c <+280>: mov    w4, #0x1
    0x102beda10 <+284>: bl     0x1038b5aa0               ; objc_msgSend$performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
->  0x102beda14 <+288>: b      0x102bed9a4               ; <+176> at UIInterface.mm:142:9
    0x102beda18 <+292>: adrp   x0, 3297
    0x102beda1c <+296>: add    x0, x0, #0xd93            ; "Check Please Error(IReferable)!"
    0x102beda20 <+300>: bl     0x1038b2364               ; symbol stub for: puts
    0x102beda24 <+304>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x60]
    0x102beda28 <+308>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x50]
    0x102beda2c <+312>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x40]
    0x102beda30 <+316>: add    sp, sp, #0x70
    0x102beda34 <+320>: ret
```

[Image with Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vknhn.png)

**Update after Comments:**

Thanks in advance for the information.

Unfortunately, the documentation for the FunSDK is not really good.
This is the documentation: https://developer.jftech.com/docs/?menusId=8af0e7f3d4af49eab71cfdd8d7e47cef&siderid=6caa41621abd4e689b21a3c0339e8cd6&lang=en

And this is a demo app in which all functions of the framework are used: https://gitlab.xmcloud.io/demo/FunSDKDemo_iOS

The documentation does not describe exactly how to call the "OnFunSDKResult" method.
At one point in the DemoApp there is only this comment: "All FUN interfaces with callback information will call back into this method."

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS error also only occurs when I implement the "OnFunSDKResult" method. So I assume that the framework somehow returns the data to the "OnFunSDKResult" method via the "UI_SendMsg".

I now basically understand that ARC released the wrapper. From the tutorials on memory management I still haven't figured out how to change this in my case.

Can someone give me a code example of how I can ensure that ARC only releases the wrapper at a certain time?
I also read that I can explicitly disable ARC for individual classes and take over memory management myself. Is this an option so that I only release the memory manually again in the "OnFunSDKResult"?

Comment: I haven't tried to integrate C++ with Objective-C in a long time. Swift/Objective C use ARC, (Automatic Reference Counting.) If you return dynamically allocated objects to Swift, you need to set up the memory semantics of your function header such that Swift knows it needs to take ownership of the object(s). I know how to do that between Objective-C and Swift, but not C++. I suggest adding a C++ tag to your question and change your subject to ask about using C++ frameworks from Swift/Objective-C

Comment: It is unclear to me how OnFunSDKResult actually gets called.  In your code, you create an instance of FunSDKWrapper, retain count of 1.  But there are no other references to that wrapper, so as soon as it goes out of scope, ARC will release it.  Retain count of zero, the object will be dealloced.  You have a non-memory-managed pointer in msgHandle internally, but you need to find a way to keep a managed reference around until OnFunSDKResult is called.  If that is guaranteed, you could have FunSDKWrapper have a retained reference to itself in the ini method, then nil it out in OnFunSDKResult.

Comment: Since you already guessed that it might be linked to the `FunSDKWrapper` object life-time, have you already tried to prolong it (e.g. by making it a property of the enclosing class). Also, could you please explain how the `OnFunSDKResult` method is called?

Comment: Thanks, I've added more info and questions as an update to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was now able to solve the problem by creating a strong reference from the FunSDKWrapper and the CompletionHandler.

```
var funSDKWrapper: FunSDKWrapper?

@objc func initXMSDK(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    
    let wrapper = FunSDKWrapper();
    self.funSDKWrapper = wrapper;
    
    let strongCompletionHandler: (([AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void) = { result in
        NSLog("Completion von iniXMSDK");
    }
    
    let resp = wrapper.iniXMSDK(1, completion: strongCompletionHandler);
    
    call.resolve([
        "status": resp
    ])

}
```